# Общий индекс для ступенчатых массивов

Tags: c#

У меня есть массив arr[][], он ступенчатый, как я могу сделать, чтобы для доступа к его элементам нужен был только один индекс.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Пример:

Если взять индекс [1][2] == [5] или [0][3] == [3]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Стандартных механизмов, для решения этой задачи нет. А так же формула расчета индексов для прямоугольного массива тоже не подходит.

Решение может быть только одно: идти по массивы и считать элементы.

Реализация может быть в лоб:

```
arr.SelectMany(cur => cur)
   .ElementAt(index)
```

Где [`SelectMany`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.selectmany?view=netcore-3.1) делает массив плоским, а [`ElementAt`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.elementat?view=netcore-3.1) берет элемент по указанному индексу.

Улучшить можно, если не считать каждый элемент, а сразу оценивать в каком из массивов расположен элемент

```
static T ByIndex2<T>(T[][] arr, int index)
{
    foreach (var item in arr)
    {
        if (index - item.Length < 0) // если разница меньше 0, значит нашли массив, а index соответствует индексу нужного элемента в найденном массиве
        {
            return item[index];
        }
        index -= item.Length;
    }

    throw new IndexOutOfRangeException(nameof(index));
}
```

Answer (score 2):

```cs
static class ArrayExtensions {
    public static T GetValueAt<T>(this T[][] arr, int index) {
        int currentIndex = 0;
        foreach (T[] arr1 in arr) {
            foreach (T i in arr1) {
                if (currentIndex == index)
                    return i;
                currentIndex++;
            }
        }
        throw new IndexOutOfRangeException();
    }
}
```

Использование:

```cs
int[][] arr = new int[][] { new int[] { 0, 1, 2, 3 }, new int[] { 4, 5, 6 } };

Console.WriteLine(arr.GetValueAt(5)); //=> 5
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    int[][] arr = new int[3][] { new int[] { 0, 1, 2, 3, 4 }, new int[] { 5, 6, 7, 8 }, new int[] { 9, 10, 11 } };

    int i = 0;
    for ( ; ; )
    {
        int ind = index;

        if ((ind -= arr[i].Length) < 0)
        {
            break;
        }

        i++;

        index = ind;
    }

    return arr[i][index];
```

Comment: на любом языке можно писать как на фортране. не надо так :)

Comment: @Grundy, Вы имеете в виду циклы? Я забыл указать, что я работаю в Unity, а там лучше не использовать foreach

Comment: Я вообще про бесконечный цикл там, где у тебя известно условие остановки.

Comment: @Grundy, Понял, Спасибо за помощь.

Comment: по сути, тут должен был быть обычный `for`, и вместо `break` - `return arr[i][index];` тогда и цикл нормально выглядит и тело цикла не будет со служебными делами возиться, вроде увеличения счетчика. В итоге получился бы тот же самый `foreach`

Comment: а что не так у unity с foreach?

Comment: @Grundy, Выделяет память, а чтобы её почистить просыпается GC, и это вызывает фризы, а так-же он медленный нежели доступа по индексам.

Comment: ну не, не может быть. Если foreach применяется к массиву его код получается такой же как и обычного цикла `for`.

Comment: @Grundy, Это да, но он ставит ненужное приведение типов. Пример: for (int i = 0; i < (uint)arr.Length; i++)

Comment: @Grundy, а это unboxing, и опять же GC

Comment: Честно говоря не вижу в il команды конвертирования. Плюс unboxing - это когда из object, идет распаковка, а в данном случае - из int в uint - скорее всего вообще ничего делаться не будет. На даже такого приведения в полученных il нет

Comment: @Grundy, да в IL командах нету, возможно это ilSpy добавляет, но вот для дженериков думаю лучше использовать for

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/111373/discussion-between-grundy-and-aimon-z).